# How can I resolve a Unicode error from read_csv?

Tags: pandas, compiler-errors, python-3.7

This is my first time working on a python project outside of school, so bear with me.

When I run the code below, I get the error

"(unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 2-3: truncated\uXXXXXXXX escape"

and the IDLE editor highlights the '(' before the argument of pd.read_csv.

I googled the error but got a lot of stuff that went way over my head.

The csv file in question is an excel file i saved as csv. should i save it some other way?

```
import pandas as pd
field = pd.read_csv("C:\Users\Glen\Documents\Feild.csv")
```

I just want to convert my excel data into a data frame and I don't understand why it was so easy in class, and it's now so difficult on my home pc.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is with the path. There are two ways to mention the path while reading a `csv` file,

1- Use `double backslashes`,

```
pd.read_csv("C:\\Users\\Glen\\Documents\\Feild.csv")
```

2- Use `single forwardslash`,

```
 pd.read_csv("C:/Users/Glen/Documents/Feild.csv")
```

If these do not work, try this one,

```
pd.read_csv("C:\\Users\\Glen\\Documents\\Feild.csv", encoding='utf-8')
```

OR

```
pd.read_csv("C:/Users/Glen/Documents/Feild.csv", encoding='utf-8')
```

Comment: Yep. It did. Thanks so much! Any chance you can explain what the error was and why it happened?

Comment: @GlenHamblin some `csv` files contains `utf-8` encoded data so when we read them, we have to mention to pandas that we are reading a file which contains `utf8` encoding. You use double `backslashes` because if we use single `backslash`, it can create confusion. E.g. if we have path something like this ... `C:\tutorial`, in this case `\t` will be considered as `tab` not as path so this creates confusion and to avoid this, use double `backslash`. In case of `forwardslash`, it's ok to use it as a single because it creates no confusion.

Comment: Worth noting, if the path is copied from e.g. Windows File Explorer (Shift+right-click > Copy as path...), just type `r` before pasting the path, to treat the single-backslashes in the pasted string as-is in a [raw string](https://note.nkmk.me/en/python-raw-string-escape/)

Answer (score 0):

**Prefix with `r` before pasting the path**

---

As @Abdur noted in [their answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56092380/4871001), the problem is with the filepath. If the path is in the clipboard (e.g. from File Explorer in Windows, Shift+right-click > Copy as Path), before pasting it into the command-line or text editor, prefix it with an `r`, as e.g.

```
field = pd.read_csv(r"C:\Users\Glen\Documents\Feild.csv")
#                   ^
#                   |
```